# Excel leaving formula when selecting another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am attempting to reference a range in another workbook in a `vlookup`.
I type `=vlookup(a1,` and then go to the other workbook to select the range, but alas, I am no longer in the `vlookup` formula. I have done this 10,000 times and it always works, but for some reason, Excel is behaving differently now. Any ideas?

Comment: And how can we reproduce this? I think though this is a question for [su].

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you running? It sounds like you have maybe opened a second application which could be your issue. If you opened your original workbook first, and then opened the excel application again and used that second window to open the other workbook, then that would be your problem.

Also, check under File > Options > Advanced > General and make sure the box titled "Ignore other applications that use DDE" is NOT checked. If so, excel will always open a new instance when opening a file. (I'm running Office 2010.)

Comment: It sounds like a second "instance" of Excel. It's easy to trigger this by opening workbooks separately from Windows Explorer. If the second file is opened via File > Open within Excel, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Gary, you've repeated the information I mentioned above.